# How can I import a file to a MDB by selecting a file in a File Dialog Box?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to vb/vba.....don't quite know about them.....
My boss ask me to develop a ms access MDB with some functions, but then first I need to create some interface for the user to import the source file for the table in the MDB.

I would like to have button "Browse", when the user press it, a file dialog box pop up and the user select the input file, then the program will use this input file and import it's data into my table, Any idea?

I am using ms access 2000 and assume the user use ms access 2000 too.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any programming experience?

Comment: Yes. I mainly use java, but for vb, I don't know anything. I've searched the internet and found some snippet, and all of them don't work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the FileDialog object. You'll need to add the Microsoft Office Object Library to your references.

Dim Filename As String
Dim df As FileDialog

Set df = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With df

.AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "Access files", "*.mdb"
  .InitialFileName = "C:\"
  .Title = "Open File"

If .Show = True Then
    Filename = .SelectedItems(0)
  End If

End With

Comment: Actually, if you don't use the named constant msoFileDialogOpen, and either define it yourself or use the literal value it stores, you don't need the reference at all. I'd strongly recommend NOT creating a reference for something like this that is so simple to use without it (because it's accessible directly from the Application object, and needs a reference only for specific data types and constants).

Comment: It said "Compiler error: user defined type not defined", and highlighted the line "Set df =Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)"

Comment: Did you add the reference to the Microsoft Office Object library? Or, as David suggested, change msoFileDialogOpen to 1? David, in response to your comment, I'm paranoid (probably overly so) about the possibility of the value of a constant changing in future versions, and on top of making the code more readable, prefer to add the reference and use the constant. In a corporate environment, using the reference doesn't add any complications. If this were for end users, though, I see your point.

Comment: It could add problems in the future, though. I'm wary of the FileDialog object, since I know the history of the FileSearch object, which in the past was also provided as a member of the Access Application object, but was removed in Office 2007. That's why I'd use it with late binding. I'd likely redefine the constant so that the code could remain. And I really think it unlikely that the argument values would change -- that would break legacy code, and MS doesn't do that kid of thing. Fer pity's sake, A2010 still includes Access 2 named constants!